# jquery autocomplete does not work for some reason

Tags: jquery

Hello I am making a searchbar which would autocomplete, but I do not get why my  copy/paste code is not working and the example on the jQuery website does work.

Did I forget to import something? I can not find my error

[My website](http://www.nugenre.net/test.html)

[The demo website](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/default.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change order of includes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

change the order of js file as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
```

Hopefully this should work.

Answer (score 0):

May be some jquery libraries are not loading for you hoverer this is working fine for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/demos/demos.css">
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo">

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" />
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->



<div class="demo-description">
<p>The Autocomplete widgets provides suggestions while you type into the field. Here the suggestions are tags for programming languages, give "ja" (for Java or JavaScript) a try.</p>
<p>The datasource is a simple JavaScript array, provided to the widget using the source-option.</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->

</body>
</html>
```